# Update parameters of a function in a while loop

Tags: gdal, while

I am trying to execute a while loop that holds a function with parameters. However, I have noticed that the parameters inside the while loop are not updated which leads to an infinite while loop. Is there a reason behind the fact that the function parameters are not being updated after every loop?

```
width1 = width
left1 = left
height1 = height
bottom1 = bottom
while pointInRect(left_face, bottom_face, left1, bottom1 , width1*0.01 , height1*0.01) :
    tods2 = gdal.Open(str(records_cntrds[i][1]))
    gt = tods2.GetGeoTransform()
    width1 = tods2.RasterXSize
    height1 = tods2.RasterYSize
    left1 = gt[0]
    bottom1 = gt[3] + width1 * gt[4] + height1 * gt[5]
    print("while executed")
    tods2.SetGeoTransform([(shapes_cntrds[i].points[0][0] - (width1 * 0.005)) - 1, 0.01, 0,
                      (shapes_cntrds[i].points[0][1] + (height1 * 0.005)) - 1, 0, -0.01])
    print("coordinates changed to",(i, left1, bottom1, width1, height1))
    tods2 = None
```

here is the pointInRect method I used

```
def pointInRect(x, y, x1, y1, w, h): # check if a raster point is in another raster

    x2, y2 = x1+w, y1+h
    if (x1 < x and x < x2):
        if (y1 < y and y < y2):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: It would be better to share `pointInRect` method. Look like it always returns `True`.

Comment: It would also help if there was some data to test with. Just a single point and rectangle where `True` is returned but `False` is expected.